# Error with session mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

When the HomeController start in the Index ActionResults i set a session with the value of 1

```
Session["login_fail"] = 1;
```

When the user try to login the sessio variable change to 0 if it fails

```
Session["login_fail"] = 0;
```

And if it fails, here what should happen

```
  @using(Html.BeginForm()) {
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Tbl_Users</legend>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="username" name="userName" /></td>
            <td id="ErrorMessage"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" /></td>
            <td id="ErrorMessage"></td>

        </tr>

        @{
        if(Convert.ToInt32(Session["login_fail"]) == 0) 
        {
                <p>User name or password are incorrect. Please, try again.</p>  //here should apper the error message if it fails but it doesnt
        }
      }
    </table>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" onclick="return validate()" value="Login" />
            </p>

        </fieldset>
```

Notice that when i submit the form, another action is who recive the values of the post and them check if the user and password are ok, if it doesnt(that i have checked that it does return 0) it will show the error message and will be return to the Index actionresults which is in the same controller as the LoginUser(the one which return 0 or 1)

Comment: Sorry, I may have missed something... but was there a question in here somewhere? :)

Comment: sorry hehe, i just want to know, why the session is not taking the new value when i redirect to the index again.

Comment: Are you using standard forms based authentication?  Could you not check the HttpContext to see if you user is logged in?  
@{if(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {...

Comment: The base Controller has it as a property too. this.User.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. The problem was that when i clicked submit the post values goes to another actionresuts, and then the session's value get 0 if the login failed and them make a redirecttoaction to Index actionresults again and the session's value for some reason, get lost.
The same as if you use a ViewBag, you can not see its value in another view. I dont know why this happen since session should be visible in the whole proyect. But i guest that that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like after your LoginUser() method, Index() works again and sets the `Session["login_fail"] = 1;` again.

You know your [Get] Index() works everytime you load the page. I suggest you to use TempData for passing data throught controller methods.

TempData["login_fail"] = 1;

So you can check if TempData is 1 or 0 in your Index() and set session according to TempData.